# preg_match move selection above paragraph

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm wanting to move images above their container paragraphs in a large body of text using preg_replace.

So, I might have

```
$body = '<p><img src="a" alt="image"></p><img src="b" alt="image"><p>something here<img src="c" alt="image"> text</p>'
```

What I want (apart from the 40' yacht etc etc);

```
<img src="a" alt="image"><p></p><img src="b" alt="image"><img src="c" alt="image"><p>something here text</p>
```

I've got this, which aint working,

```
$body = preg_replace('/(<p>.*\s*)(<img.*\s*?image">)(.*\s*?<\/p>)/', '$2$1$3',$body);
```

It results in;

```
<img src="c" alt="image"><p><img src="a" alt="image"></p><img src="b" alt="image"><p>something here text</p>
```

Comment: use a parser instead of regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the HTML with `DOMDocument` and use its operations to move nodes around:

```
$content = <<<EOM
<p><img src="a" alt="image"></p>
<img src="b" alt="image"><p>something here<img src="c" alt="image"> text</p>
EOM;

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

// find images that are a direct descendant of a paragraph
foreach ($xp->query('//p/img') as $img) {
        $parent = $img->parentNode;
        // move image as a previous sibling of its parent
        $parent->parentNode->insertBefore($img, $parent);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, works perfectly. Now I'm off to find out what this DOMDocument is all about ...